# TFS Build - <Latest> not showing any configurations, all completed builds are

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Something has managed to break on my TFS build. Whenever my deployment build is selected to a specific build, it shows the possible configurations (in my case dev1, dev2, test1, test2 and prd). However when I select <Latest> it disables the possible configurations. My deployment relies on this so it fails.

Where does TFS get these configurations for <Latest>? I'd have thought from the latest successful build. But this does have configurations when I select that specific build.

Any tips?

Comment: When I select it, being Latest option.

Comment: What deployment tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, guess you are using release management for the deployment.

If you select `<Latest>,` release management will catch the latest **successful build** of the build definition. It will ignored the failed build. Just as you guessed.

If you select `<specific build>`, then it will list the all successful build result of the build definition.